# Using COLLADA DOM to get the next tag with the same name

Tags: xml, dom, collada

Im using COLLADA DOM to access the data in a .dae file and there are multiple tags called float_array... i can access the first using getDecendant("float_array") but how would i access the next for the normals and textures??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dae.getDatabase()->idLookup("Cube-Geometry-Position-array", root->getDocument());`
Found the idLookup method so instead of searching for an element name, search for its ID as all ID's are individual